# PHP MYSQLI_ASYNC Insert Query and continue

Tags: php, mysqli, mariadb, php-7.2

Is there a way to continue in a PHP7.2 script after using

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `table` SET `a` = 'aaa';
$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql,MYSQLI_ASYNC);
// $result is always 'true'
```

as a means of a delayed insert?

It now gives 
`Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now` when my script continues and the next query is executed.

I'm using innodb so an `INSERT DELAYED` doesn't work, although I'm looking for the same behavior from a PHP script perspective. (deploy query, don't wait for it being processed)

Do I need to use a separate script and message broker (e.g. RabbitMQ) to pull this off with InnoDB databases?

Answer (score -2):

Yes, `MYSQLI_ASYNC` will return immediately from `mysqli_query()`.

But the MySQL/MariaDB session may still be busy when you run the next query, which then will give you a "*Commands out of sync*" error.

So, you have to care for

- waiting for an (unknown) amount of time before running further queries
- not calling `mysqli_close()` on that session until the async query has finished, otherwise the connection barfs
- not even let PHP script end, as that calls `mysqli_close()` implicitly, as far as I know.

The conclusion is: don't use `MYSQLI_ASYNC`, unless you're in a very uncommon environment, which uses multiple parallel connections, never lets a connection end, and fires no further queries on the same session.

Answer (score -3):

There is no good reason to run `INSERT` asynchronously; it is likely to be very fast.

Ditto for `UPDATE` or `DELETE`, unless there are millions of rows being updated or deleted.

Comment: There is a good reason, when you have a replicated backend that has a master-master setup there is a small delay when inserting a row cause it makes sure all databases are in sync. I don't want my php script to wait for that, cause I'm not interested in the outcome of the query.

Comment: @Sergeant - Do you really mean just Master-Master?  If so, that configuration is _not_ synchronous.  "Semi-sync" may have an issue; Galera could have an issue if the nodes are geographically spread apart.